# How do I add text to an object mid animation?

Tags: animation

I have a cube which changes colour at frame 10 & 20 then changes size at 30 but at frame 40 I want to add text. I also want the text to change colour at frame 60. I cannot find a tutorial about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use text object (Shift+A>Text) or create a texture with no background and text on it and add it to the cube and mix color You like the text to have with cube color using Alpha channel of this texture.